# Connected App OAuth Scopes - full vs. api

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps, oauth

I'm wondering if anyone could clarify for me the distinction between the connected app Oauth scopes 'full' vs. 'api'.

We have a couple integrations for which I've used 'web' and 'api', and they work fine, but I'm curious what access to resources 'full' would grant to the client app that the other scopes do not.

I have read the available Salesforce docs on this and did not find them to be too illuminating.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This [help page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_tokens_scopes.htm&type=5) talks about oauth scopes, which I believe you went through.

`api` scope grants access to execute rest api, bulk api etc., However it doesn't allow to access other aspects like custom permissions for which you need `custom_permissions` scope.

Granting `full` gives all possible access the granting user has access to, except `refresh_token` which needs to be explicitly requested.

Comment: Thanks. That helps. I'm wondering if you might be able to provide a sample use case of when I would choose full as opposed to api?

Comment: You would always choose just the scopes you application needs to function. If your application needs just api access, start with api and then later you can add more if required.